# Why did I get different answers when I changed grep to egrep in the latter half of each

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
$ egrep "^COMP[29]041" enrolments | grep "|F$" | wc -l
24
$ egrep "^COMP[29]041" enrolments | egrep "|F$" | wc -l
166
$
```

The content of file `enrolments`:

```
COMP2041|4836917|Ruld, Ruld                       |3978/2|M
COMP2041|4850109|Rvyiparzal, Ilbvuy               |3979/3|M
COMP2041|2858836|Rzild, Fia Held                  |3730/4|M
COMP2041|4823158|Sheld, Yild                      |3978/2|M
COMP2041|4818044|Sheo, Sheo                       |3978/2|M
COMP2041|4818497|Sheo, Xa                         |3978/2|M
COMP9041|4899688|Shild, Ge                        |8680/2|M
COMP2041|4869506|Shild, Yild                      |3645/2|M
COMP9041|4897426|Shild, Yild                      |8680/2|M
COMP9041|4368551|Sho, Wuld                        |8684  |M
COMP2041|4339940|Shuld, Puaxail Baili             |3978/3|F
COMP2041|4330093|Veh, Yeold-He                    |3711/3|M
COMP2041|2230267|Vikil, Ivrha                     |3978/3|F
COMP2041|4312663|Viy Chiobhova, Jiozrigh          |3978/1|M
.......
```

The question is why I got different answers when I changed `grep` to `egrep` in the latter half of each. 
What are the differences between `grep` and `egrep`?

Comment: The 'what is the difference' part of this question is equivalent to the Unix SE question; the example material is totally unrepresented in the off-site duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `egrep` (or, preferably, [`grep -E`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)), the `|` is a metacharacter, whereas in plain `grep` it is a plain (non-meta) character.

The `|F$` term in `egrep` looks for an empty string or `F` at the end of line; it finds an empty string on every line.

The same term in `grep` looks for a `|F` at the end of line.  To look for that with `egrep`, you'd need to escape the metacharacter with a backslash: `grep -E '\|F$' enrolments`.

In short, the plain `grep` command understands [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE).  The `egrep` or 'extended `grep`' command understands [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (ERE).  Some versions of `grep` (such as GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs)) can be compiled to recognize [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](https://www.pcre.org/) (PCRE).

Comment: Why is `grep -E` preferred over `egrep`? Is it because `egrep` can get deprecated in future? I can see than there are some advantages of using unified binary, same as why people use busybox; but is there any other reasons? Like code standardization?

Comment: @anishsane: Yes; `egrep` is not documented in POSIX any more.  The rationale (on the same page I referenced) says: _This `grep` has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical `egrep` and `fgrep` commands as well. It was the clear intention of the standard developers to consolidate the three greps into a single command.
The old `egrep` and `fgrep` commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified._